# VMware: kernel headers not found!

Tags: kernel, vmware, vmware-workstation

Just updated my ubuntu to 20.04 and when i tried to run VMware and VMware Kernel Module started compiling Virtual Machine Monitor and Virtual Network Device and it failed
i started VMware using terminal and i had this issues:

> /bin/sh: 1: flex: not found

which i fixed by installing flex
and

> Cannot open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory

that i don't exactly remember how i fixed and now i'm getting this [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqSAM.jpg) that says:

> Kernel headers for version 5.4.0-39-generic were not found

but i have headers installed as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsV7k.png)!

Comment: I had a similar problem. This instruction page helped me https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime that my Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS updates something related to the kernel, VMware Workstation stops working and errors out with the same message that you are reporting: Kernel Headers not found.

The following solution works, most of the times, for me.

#### Manually installing the missing headers

Open a terminal and install the headers that VMware wants; following your screenshot, the command should be:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
```

After this installation, restart VMware and it should change the error window for a window of "Several modules must be compiled and loaded into the kernel". Press <kbd>Continue</kbd>, and wait until it finishes.
If says an error mid-instalation, close VMware and try it again; most of the times I have to go though some errors before it finishes correctly.

Please do note that, at least in my case, the linux-headers version it wants tends to be different every time this error appears.

But sometimes, the solution above will not work, and ocasionally I'll find out that VMware requieres an already-installed header that does not want to be detected (like your problem).

#### Removing and reinstalling the required headers

We are going to remove the header VMware is referring to and then manually reinstall it.

First of all, run this command to see which header is currently in use:

```
uname -r
```

If the current header is the one that VMware is complaining about, then **DON'T CONTINUE**.
Only remove the header version if you know that you are not using it currently.

To remove a header, just do an `apt purge` like you would do with any other apt package.

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
```

Now that's removed, reinstall it again with:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
```

Once installed, fire up VMware again and see if it works or not.